# Angular app not loading on Safari, but works in chrome

Tags: angular, browser, safari

My application is working fine on chrome, but in safari not loading immediately and content is also not displaying properly.
is there any issue with Platform Browser Dynamic..?
and is there any problem with polyfills

This is for Safari browser on Mac

```
// loading JS files in index.html  
 <!-- jQuery JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Plugins JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- Ajax Mail -->
    <script src="./assets/js/ajax-mail.js"></script>
    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/main_page.js"></script>
```

```
// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[This is the error in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyP0j.png)

When i comment the above line i'm able to load in chrome but not on safari
when i un comment it then there is an error in chrome also
The errors be like $(...).jquery is not function
ModelType is missing

Comment: Which Safari version are you using? Can you check in polyfills if current safari version is supported by Angular your version

Comment: I'm using safari 12.2
My pollyfill.ts will support safari >= 10

Comment: Hi - were you able to figure out why you were running into this issue?